# How to extract a picture from Manipulate, without frame, sliders and axes?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, export

I would like to extract some pictures from a `Manipulate` that uses a slider, but when I do it from the pop-up menu, I get all the frame and slider with it.  How can we export the picture (to PNG, say), for a given slider value (say $k = 0.5$, for the example below), without the Manipulate frame, slider, and even without the axes and ticks?

And probably trickier: how can we extract the graphics with an higher resolution than what the Manipulate shows? (say 1024 x 1024 pixels in PNG format, instead of the lower resolution of 600 below).

Here's a semi-cool MWE to play with:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  Cos[x + y] Sin[k x - 3 y],
  {x, -2, 2},
  {y, -2, 2},
  PlotPoints -> 20,
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5]],
  AxesLabel -> {
    Style["X",  Bold, 14],
    Style["Y",  Bold, 14]
    },
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  ContourStyle -> Black,
  Contours -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 600
  ],
 {
  k, -5, 5, 0.1,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"},
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}
  },
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
 FrameMargins -> None,
 FrameLabel ->  {None, None, 
   Style["Some Funny Title", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}
 ]
```

Comment: I click on the graphics and Edit > Copy.  You can also click on the circled + button in the upper-right corner of the Manipulate frame and 'Paste Snapshot".  For output, use `Export` on the copied graphics.

Comment: @MichaelE2, the problem with this method is you can't choose the format (PNG say) and resolution.  Or maybe there is but I don't know it.

Comment: @MarcoB, I understand for the resolution.  I was extracting the picture by hand, by re-running the Manipulate code with a few modifications (remove axes, etc), but it's clumsy.

Comment: One of the ways I use quite often is to just go `Manipulate[plt = ContourPlot[...], ...]`. Then, when you change your sliders, the new image is stored to `plt`. Then, `Export["path/plot.png", plt, ImageSize -> {1024, 1024}]`. The resolution in your code isn't 600, that's just a width (well, I suppose it might end up being the resolution if there are no other options given on export). I usually choose a target resolution when exporting and ignore the size like `Export["path/plot.png", plt, ImageResolution -> 300]`.

Comment: I can pick the resolution and format for exporting graphics.  Look up PNG in the docs.

Comment: @MassDefect, can you show your method as an answer?

Comment: You'll want to set `TrackedSymbols` in @MassDefect 's solution, or you'll recompute the plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
  plt = ContourPlot[
    Cos[x + y] Sin[k x - 3 y], 
    {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    PlotPoints -> 20, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
    Axes -> True, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5]], 
    AxesLabel -> {Style["X", Bold, 14], Style["Y", Bold, 14]}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    ContourStyle -> Black, 
    Contours -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 600
  ], 
  {k, -5, 5, 0.1, ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}, AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom, 
  FrameMargins -> None, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, None, Style["Some Funny Title", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}
]

Export["~/Desktop/test.png", plt, ImageSize -> {1024, 1024}]

            (* or *)

Export["~/Desktop/test.png", plt, ImageResolution -> 300]

            (* EDIT *)

Export["~/Desktop/test.png", plt[[1]]//Graphics, ImageSize -> {1024, 1024}]
```

This saves the frame generated by the slider setting to a variable called `plt`. Every time the slider changes, `plt` is updated. Then, I typically use the `Export` command so that I can more easily control the various parameters. A bit of an aside: one export parameter that I quite like is `Background -> None`. Not really relevant here, but it allows you to export PNG images with no background. Looks really slick when adding to a poster or presentation if the graphics have sufficient contrast with the background.

To get just the graphics form the `ContourPlot` I used @andre314's method of taking the first element of `plt` and turning it into a graphic, namely `plt[[1]]//Graphics`.

The result of the above code with `ImageSize -> {1024, 1024}` is:

[image: Exported contour plot.]

The result of the final export statement from above is:

[image: Exported contour plot with no ticks.]

Comment: Wooaa!  This is cool!

Comment: @Cham Although I just realized that you asked to export with no ticks or axes labels either. You can actually just use the last step shown by Andre314 above. I'll add that to my answer (with attribution).

Comment: It works, and it's neat!!  This is awesome!  Apparently, it doesn't work of Plot3D, though.

Comment: @Cham `Plot3D` gives 3d graphics. We can fix it by using `Graphics3D[plt[[1]], Boxed -> False]` in place of `plt[[1]]//Graphics`.

Comment: Yep, it fixes this issue.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

I have found something simplier than my first answer:

Apply `Setting` to the Manipulate to obtain a normal graphic.

Then to remove all the options of this graphic, one way is to take the first part and reapply `Graphic`

[image]
**END EDIT**

**OLD ANSWER**

You can use the Snapshot function in the Manipulate.

Then remplace `DynamicModule` by `With` (this may not be necessary),
then the evaluation of this gives a normal `Graphics`.
To remove all the options of this graphic, one way is to take the first part and reapply `Graphic`

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to remember what the name of `Setting` was. +1