# Optimized GIF 20s for 85kb for Mathematica Code Demonstration

Tags: manipulate, windows, video, gif-format, compression

I’m new here this is my first post on Stack Exchange. In the thread below, I see that a GIF file is highly optimized (20s for 85kb) with no noticeable compromise in resolution. It appears to be the best way to demonstrate how code works for Mathematica and other programs.

[graphics - How to extract a picture from Manipulate, without frame, sliders and axes? - Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236139/how-to-extract-a-picture-from-manipulate-without-frame-sliders-and-axes)

[pS7ov.gif (789×762) (imgur.com)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS7ov.gif)

I did try to produce it by editing a screen-recorded clip and exporting it as a GIF file through Adobe Premiere Pro renderer. The quality was acceptable, but the file was so huge (xx Mb).

I'm reaching out to seek guidance on creating optimized GIFs, and I would greatly appreciate any assistance or advice you can offer. If possible, please tell me how to use free software on Windows for this.

P.S. I noticed that user [@andre314](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5467/andre314) is the owner of the example GIF above. If you're reading this, I would be grateful for your insights and suggestions on this topic!

Comment: I doubt that the screen capture or GIF generation was done with Mathematica. I for one use [LiceCAP](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) for that. It normally generates a pretty small animated GIF file. You can also adjust the frame rate to control size.

Comment: I use the tool [giphy capture](https://giphy.com/apps/giphycapture), which makes animations (gif or mp4) that look very similar to the one you linked.  It even uses flashing circles to indicate mouse button press, so maybe it is the tool that was used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I use [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/), which is very easy to use and results in very small files without a lot of work. It can even upload the images directly to Imgur. I tried to recreate the GIF you linked, and without any tweaking, I got a 123KB file:

[image]

Changing the encoder to Octree, I got it down to 83KB:

[image]